# Rails 4 + Devise Separate User CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4 to build a simple Admin interface for adding and removing users, or CRUD.

I'm currently having Devise installed and have built the basic views and actions.

However after filling out the forms myself, this is what I get:

> 2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
>
> Email can't be blank
>
> Password can't be blank

This is what I have currently: (removed registerable since I don't want to have a public registration)

**Models > user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**views > users > new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create User" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**routes.rb** (currently I make new user through "/admin/users/new" )

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  scope '/admin' do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

**Controllers > users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[user_params])

    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => 'User was successfully created.' }
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[user_params])
      sign_in(@user, :bypass => true) if @user == current_user
      redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => 'User was successfully updated.' }
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :flash => { :success => 'User was successfully deleted.' }
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what is causing the error?
Thanks :D

Just a note: previously, before I disabled :registerable in devise_modules in user.rb, I can actually perform sign-ups using the default devise view "users/sign_up". However what I want is still to get an admin CRUD system, so I disabled it anyway.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you need an Admin interface to perform CRUD actions, why not use [rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)?

Comment: Yeah rails_admin should be a choice for admin side. BTW do u have validation on user model ?

Comment: hi @mmichael must've missed it, it looks awesome, one thing I noticed is that the last build is failing (in github page)?. Will look further into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it typo in your `def create/update`:

```
@user = User.new(params[user_params])
# should be
@user = User.new(user_params)

if @user.update_attributes(params[user_params])
# should be
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

Comment: wow, can't believe I missed that. Kinda peeved with rails for not notifying me about the error though. It worked now, thanks!